# Fastest way to search a list for strings for superstrings of a given string in python

Tags: python, string, list

I'm working on a project that requires checking a string against a very large list of strings, searching for occasions where the string is a substring of one of the elements of the list.

Originally I had this method:

```
def isSubstring(subWord, words):
    for superWord in words:
            if superWord.find(subWord) != -1 and len(subWord) != len(superWord):
                return True

    return False

def checkForSubstrings(words):
    words.sort(key=len, reverse=False)

    while len(words) > 1:
        currentWord = words.pop(0)

        if isSubstring(currentWord, words):
            print("%s is a substring of some other string" % currentWord)
```

Sort all the strings by length, for each word, compare it only to the longer words.

But this method has a flaw in that words are still being compared to words of the same length which are arbitrarily placed after it during the list sort.

So I changed the `checkForSubstring` method:

```
def checkForSubstring(words):
    sameLengthWordsLists = [[w for w in words if len(w) == num] for num in set(len(i) for i in words)]

    for wordList in sameLengthWordsLists:
        words = words[len(wordList):]

        if len(words) == 0:
             break

        for currentWord in wordList:
            if isSubsumed(currentWord, words):
                print("%s is a substring of some other string" % currentWord)
```

Instead of sorting by length, this version splits the list of strings into many lists by length and then checks each of these lists against every list of larger words. This solves the earlier problem.

But it's not appreciably faster, could someone suggest a faster way to do this? At the moment, it's a bottleneck.

Comment: Have you looked at [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html)?

Comment: What exactly is your input: a list of words or a list of lists of words?

Comment: here is one though: if A is a substring of B, and C is the set of strings such as A is a substring of each element of C, (B is in C), then all superstrings of B are in C. (example: A = foo, B = foobar, C = [foobar, foobarbaz, foobaz]). So, by going in ascending sizes, you can start by looking if there are any strings previously considered that is a substring of the current string. You only need to test those.

Comment: `words = words[len(wordList):]` should not work, though, because you are replacing the variable `words`, so the index is wrong. Plus the whole thing does not work because `set` is not sorted, so your sameLengthWordsLists does not contain the words in the order in which they are in the `words` list

Comment: @schwobaseggl: input is a list of words

Comment: @njzk2: the `sameLengthWordsLists` does not need to contain them in the same order as they were in `words`, as long as each element is a list of words of the same length. Also, `words = words[len(wordList):]` does work?

Answer (score 1):

Following my comment, something like this:

```
def checkForSubstrings(words):
  # e.g: fo: [foo, foobar]
  super_strings = defaultdict(list)
  # e.g: foo: [fo, oo]
  substrings = defaultdict(list)
  words.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
  while words:
    # Nota: pop(0) is highly inefficient, as it moves all the list
    word = words.pop()
    subwords = substrings[word]
    # finding the smallest list of words that contain a substring of `word`
    current_words = min(super_strings[w] for w in subwords, key=len)
    if not current_words:
      current_words = words
    super_words = [w for w in current_words if len(w) > len(word) and w.find(word) > -1]
    for s in super_words:
      substrings[s].append(word)
    super_strings[word] = super_words
  # the result is in super_strings
```

If no 2 words are substrings, or if all are, this does not change anything. However, if only some are, it should speed some things up. That and using `pop()` instead of `pop(0)`

Comment: Interesting. I'm trying to get this to work but can't because of the line `current_words = min(super_strings[w] for w in subwords, key=len)`. Could you please clarify a little what that line is meant to be doing?

Comment: for that matter, what is `current_words` supposed to do? I don't see it being used anywhere.

Comment: should be used instead of `words` afterwards. fixing it now

Comment: @EmmetOT because `foo` was found in `foobar` and `foobaz` (and only in those), `foobar` is only searched in those, instead of all the words. If there is more than one known substring previously found, (for example, `foo` and `bar`), we look for the smallest set

Answer (score 0):

If the **LARGE** string list is not that big, you may build a **HUGE** dict with every possible contiguous substrings in it. Taking the benefit of that index dict, the time-complexity of every following search will drop down to O(1), that may speed things up A LOT.

Below is my example code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

text = """Sort all the strings by length, for each word, compare it only to the longer words.

But this method has a flaw in that words are still being compared to words of the same length which are arbitrarily placed after it during the list sort.

So I changed the "checkForSubstring" method:"""


def checkForSubstrings(words):
    # Building a big dict first, this may be a little slow and cosuming a lot memory
    d = defaultdict(set)
    for windex, word in enumerate(words):
        # Get all possible substrings of word
        for i in range(len(word)):
            for j in range(len(word)):
                if word[i:j+1]:
                    # Put (word_index, matches_whole) to our dict
                    d[word[i:j+1]].add((windex, word[i:j+1] == word))

    # You may call sys.getsizeof(d) to check memory usage
    # import sys; print sys.getsizeof(d)

    # Iter over words, find matches bug ignore the word itself
    for windex, word in enumerate(words):
        matches = d.get(word, [])
        for obj in matches:
            if not obj[1]:
                print("%s is a substring of some other string" % word)
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = text.lower().split()
    checkForSubstrings(words)
```

Result of this script:

```
sort is a substring of some other string
for is a substring of some other string
compare is a substring of some other string
it is a substring of some other string
method is a substring of some other string
a is a substring of some other string
in is a substring of some other string
words is a substring of some other string
are is a substring of some other string
words is a substring of some other string
length is a substring of some other string
are is a substring of some other string
it is a substring of some other string
so is a substring of some other string
i is a substring of some other string
```